# Two jcombobox options displaying path

Tags: java, directory, jcombobox, subdirectory

I need to display two connected combo boxes with directory names. There is a start path which contains multiple directories that are displayed in the first jcombobox, and when a directory is selected, the sub directories need to be displayed in the second jcombobox. The second jcombobox should be able to select one of those sub directories. Each of sub sub directories contains multiple .txt files. I managed to display the directories and sub directories on both jcomboboxes including the files.

```
package calc.my.pay;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class CalcMyPay extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JComboBox folderSelector, subFolderSelector;
    private File[] directory, subDirectory;

    private String subPath, finalSubPath, selectedSubDirectory, finalSubDirectory;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CalcMyPay frame = new CalcMyPay();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * @throws IOException 
     */

    public CalcMyPay() 
    {   
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(350, 10, 1000, 700);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(12, 120, 958, 300);

        String startPath = "C:/Users/Zeus/Desktop/Content/";

        // The starting path of the file
        directory = new File(startPath).listFiles();

        // Folders dropdown box
        folderSelector = new JComboBox();
        folderSelector.setBounds(60, 13, 200, 22);
        folderSelector.insertItemAt("Choose directory", 0);
        folderSelector.setSelectedIndex(0);
        for(int i=0; i < directory.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(directory[i]);
            folderSelector.addItem(directory[i].getName());
        }
        contentPane.add(folderSelector);

        // Sub folder dropdown box
        subFolderSelector = new JComboBox();
        subFolderSelector.setBounds(300, 13, 200, 22);
        subFolderSelector.insertItemAt("Choose subdirectory", 0);
        subFolderSelector.setSelectedIndex(0);
        contentPane.add(subFolderSelector);

        folderSelector.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Get the folder dropdown selected item
                selectedSubDirectory = folderSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();
                //System.out.println("Folder selected: " + Arrays.asList(directory).toString().contains(selectedSubDirectory));
                //System.out.println("Subfolders based on folder selected : " + Arrays.asList(directory) + "         " + selectedSubDirectory);
                //subFolderSelector.addItem(folderSelector.getSelectedItem());

                // Check if the array from the main directory contains the selected directory
                if(Arrays.asList(directory).toString().contains(selectedSubDirectory)) {
                    // Make a new file that list all the directories in the given path
                    subPath = startPath + selectedSubDirectory;
                    subDirectory = new File(subPath).listFiles();
                    // Sort the array directory in a descending order
                    Arrays.sort(subDirectory, Collections.reverseOrder());
                    // Delete the previous list items, if any
                    subFolderSelector.removeAllItems();
                    // Iterate through all the directories in the selected folder
                    for(int i=0; i < subDirectory.length; i++) {
                        // Pass only directories (files will be omitted)
                        // ### Should check if directory contains only 4 numbers here
                        if(subDirectory[i].isDirectory()) {
                        //subFolderSelector.addItem(folderSelector.getSelectedItem());
                            subFolderSelector.addItem(subDirectory[i].getName());
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        subFolderSelector.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            int count = 0;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++;
                if(count == 3) {
                    selectedSubSubDirectory = subFolderSelector.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    // Make an new file that list all the file in the selected sub folder
                    if(Arrays.asList(subDirectory).toString().contains(selectedSubDirectory)) {
                        //textFiles = new File(finalSubPath).listFiles();

                        subSubPath = startPath + selectedSubDirectory + "/" + selectedSubSubDirectory;
                        textFiles = new File(subSubPath).listFiles();

                        for(File file: textFiles) {
                            if(file.isFile() && file.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith("_110.txt")) {
                                System.out.println(file);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

However as you can see in the second actionListener for the subDirectorySelector i have a counter. The code there executes three times (because the second jcombobox changes value). There is an error if you select the same path twice in the first jcombobox. There must be a better (and possibly) shorter way to do this. What would you change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make my own version but it's really similar, except I removed the actionListener before updating the subFolder selector and I added more checks.

Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ComboDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private String rootDir;
    private JComboBox box1;
    private JComboBox box2;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ComboDemo () {
        super("Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        createGui();
        this.rootDir = "/home";
        setRootDir(new File(this.rootDir));
    }

    /**
     * Create the gui components.
     */
    private void createGui () {
        this.box1 = new JComboBox();
        this.box2 = new JComboBox();
        this.box1.addActionListener(this);
        this.box2.addActionListener(this);

        this.box1.insertItemAt("Choose directory :", 0);
        this.box1.setSelectedIndex(0);
        this.box2.insertItemAt("Choose subdirectory :", 0);
        this.box2.setSelectedIndex(0);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        add(this.box1);
        add(this.box2);
    }

    /**
     * Show the gui.
     */
    private void showGui () {
        setSize(500, 250);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Update the first selector with the directories listed under the specified
     * root directory.
     * 
     * @param dir
     *            Root directory.
     */
    private void setRootDir (File dir) {
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                this.box1.addItem(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JComboBox) {
            JComboBox box = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

            // Box 1
            if (this.box1.equals(box)) {
                String dirName = box.getSelectedItem().toString();
                // RootDir / Folder
                File dir = new File(this.rootDir + File.separator + dirName);
                System.out.println("# Folder : " + dir.getPath());

                // Check if there is a least one file
                if (dir.exists() && dir.listFiles().length > 0) {
                    Arrays.sort(dir.listFiles(), Collections.reverseOrder());

                    // Reset box2
                    this.box2.removeAllItems();
                    this.box2.insertItemAt("Choose subdirectory :", 0);

                    // Update Box2
                    this.box2.removeActionListener(this);
                    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                        if (file.isDirectory()) {
                            this.box2.addItem(file.getName());
                        }
                    }
                    this.box2.addActionListener(this);
                    this.box2.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
            }
            // Box 2
            else if (this.box2.equals(box)) {
                // Check if box2 is empty
                if (box.getItemCount() > 0) {
                    String dirName = box.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    // RootDir / Folder / SubFolder
                    File dir = new File(this.rootDir + File.separator + this.box1.getSelectedItem().toString()
                            + File.separator + dirName);
                    System.out.println("# SubFolder : " + dir.getPath());

                    // Check if there is a least one file
                    if (dir.exists() && dir.listFiles().length > 0) {
                        Arrays.sort(dir.listFiles(), Collections.reverseOrder());

                        // Print .txt files
                        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                                System.out.println("\t" + file.getName());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ComboDemo demo = new ComboDemo();
        demo.showGui();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i guess that this is another way to solve the same problem. Multiple if's are helpful indeed.